# Dependencias faltantes para sqlite3 en ubuntu

Tags: linux, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu

Estoy comenzando a trabajar con Ruby on rails en ubuntu 14.04.

Al hacer $bundle install 
me aparece el siguiente error:

```
An error occurred while installing sqlite3 (1.3.11), and Bundler cannot
continue.
Make sure that `gem install sqlite3 -v '1.3.11'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Buscando en la red encontré que debía ingresar el siguiente comando:

```
$sudo apt-get install libsqlite3-dev
```

Sin embargo, me aparece otro error.

```
Leyendo lista de paquetes... Hecho
Creando árbol de dependencias       
Leyendo la información de estado... Hecho
No se pudieron instalar algunos paquetes. Esto puede significar que
usted pidió una situación imposible o, si está usando la distribución
inestable, que algunos paquetes necesarios no han sido creados o han
sido movidos fuera de Incoming.
La siguiente información puede ayudar a resolver la situación:

Los siguientes paquetes tienen dependencias incumplidas:
 libsqlite3-dev : Depende: libsqlite3-0 (= 3.8.2-1ubuntu2) pero 3.8.2-1ubuntu2.1 va a ser instalado
E: No se pudieron corregir los problemas, usted ha retenido paquetes rotos.
```

Comment: hiciste el `gem install sqlite3 -v '1.3.11` en tu consola ?

Answer (score 1):

Mirando en la version inglesa de SO veo esta solución:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3458602/sqlite3-ruby-install-error-on-ubuntu

Recomiendan instalar primero lo siguiente:

`sudo apt-get install libxslt-dev libxml2-dev`

Al parecer tenéis el mismo problema por lo que esto podría funcionarte.

Answer (score 1):

Haz en tu consola el siguiente comando `gem install sqlite3 -v '1.3.11'`
despues realiza el `bundle install`

Answer (score 0):

Este error por lo general se da cuando se intenta crear una base de datos o cargar una aplicación rails que tenga sqlite como base de datos principal, pero el sistema operativo no tiene el cliente sqlite instalado previamente.

Podrías usar la siguiente linea para instalarlo.

```
sudo apt-get install sqlite3 libsqlite3-dev
```